# Adding custom field to custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a couple of custom post type. To one of them i also want to add a custom field. It should just be a simple textfield where you can enter some text. Similar to the title field. How would you do that? I dont want to use a plugin.

Current code (functions.php)

```
    register_post_type( 'cases',
      array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Cases' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Case' )
        ),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cases'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      )
    );
```

Comment: Are you editing the core files?

Comment: No. i dont. im working in functions.php

Comment: You can add custom field to post under screen options, did you try that?

Comment: http://cdn2.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/screenoptions-cf.png check here

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I have tried that But the setting does not apply to my custom post types, only to the defaukt post type.

Comment: Honestly, Advanced custom fields, makes it so much faster and easier. And if you don't want to have the plugin activated, you can export it as php code, and put it in your functions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create custom meta box and add that field within metabox.

**Create Metabox**

```
function add_your_fields_meta_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'your_fields_meta_box', // $id
    'Your Fields', // $title
    'show_your_fields_meta_box', // $callback
    'your_post', // $screen
    'normal', // $context
    'high' // $priority
);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_fields_meta_box' );
```

**Html part**

```
function show_your_fields_meta_box() {
global $post;  
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_fields', true ); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="your_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

<!-- All fields will go here -->

<?php }
```

**Save field in database**

```
function save_your_fields_meta( $post_id ) {   
// verify nonce
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
    return $post_id; 
}
// check autosave
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check permissions
if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    } elseif ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }  
}

$old = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', true );
$new = $_POST['your_fields'];

if ( $new && $new !== $old ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', $new );
} elseif ( '' === $new && $old ) {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', $old );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_your_fields_meta' );
```

For more detail you can check here https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-part-three-custom-fields-and-metaboxes/, This is very nice link which will help you to create custom  meta box and field step by step

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19182354)

Comment: You are right Philipp this link will be useful for current one user but in future if anyone will have same issue then couldn't be useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is way late, but under your function, you need to add 'custom-fields' to your support:

```
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'custom-fields'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom fields, you have to add metabox.
See my example that will help you.

```
function show_your_fields_meta_box() {
    global $post;  
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_fields', true ); ?>
// Just paste your input here as below.
        <input type="hidden" name="your_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">
        <p>
            <label for="your_fields[text]">Input Text</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="your_fields[text]" id="your_fields[text]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['text']; ?>">
        </p>


    <?php }


function save_your_fields_meta( $post_id ) {   
    // verify nonce
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['your_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
        return $post_id; 
    }
    // check autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // check permissions
    if ( 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        } elseif ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }  
    }

    $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', true );
    $new = $_POST['your_fields'];

    if ( $new && $new !== $old ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', $new );
    } elseif ( '' === $new && $old ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_fields', $old );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_your_fields_meta' ); 

?>
```