# Add extra filed in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my code

```
    // Our custom post type function
function create_posttype_ticket() {

    register_post_type( 'ticket',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Ticket' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'ticket'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_ticket' );
```

I want add some more label/text box in custom post type

**Movie : Release Date**

**Movie : Cast**

any idea

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405620/adding-custom-field-to-custom-post-type-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in function.php or in your plugin file.

This code will create some custom fields in your **custom post type**.

```
function movie_detail_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box(
        'movie_detail_box_id',  // Unique ID
        'Movie Details',  // Box title
        'render_movie_detail_meta_box_html',
        'ticket',  // Post type
        'normal',
        'low'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'movie_detail_meta_box');


function render_movie_detail_meta_box_html($post){
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    wp_nonce_field( 'movie_detail_metabox', 'movie_detail_metabox_nonce' );

    $val_movie_name = ( isset( $meta['movie_name'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['movie_name'][0] ) ? $meta['movie_name'][0] : '';
    $val_movie_release = ( isset( $meta['movie_release'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['movie_release'][0] ) ? $meta['movie_release'][0] : '';
    $val_movie_cast = ( isset( $meta['movie_cast'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['movie_cast'][0] ) ? $meta['movie_cast'][0] : '';

    // print_r("<p>val_autoplayTime-".$val_autoplayTime."<p/>");
    echo "<div class='movie_meta_fields_container'>";

    echo '<p><label for="movie_name"><b>Movie Name: </b></label><input type="text" name="movie_name" id="movie_name" style="width:100%;" value="'. esc_attr( $val_movie_name ) .'"></p>';

    echo '<p><label for="movie_release"><b>Movie Release: </b></label><input type="text" name="movie_release" id="movie_release" style="width:100%;" value="'. esc_attr( $val_movie_release ) .'"></p>';

    echo '<p><label for="movie_cast"><b>Movie Cast: </b></label><input type="text" name="movie_cast" id="movie_cast" style="width:100%;" value="'. esc_attr( $val_movie_cast ) .'"></p>';

    echo "</div>";
}


function movie_detail_save_metadata($post_id){
    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['movie_detail_metabox_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['movie_detail_metabox_nonce'] ), 'movie_detail_metabox' ) ) { // Input var okay.
            return $post_id;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }

     // OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. 

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( !isset($_POST['movie_name']) || !isset($_POST['movie_release']) || !isset($_POST['movie_cast']) ) {
        return;
    }

    $fields = ['movie_name','movie_release','movie_cast'];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (array_key_exists($field, $_POST)){
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]));
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'movie_detail_save_metadata');
```

Feel free to ask, if you got stuck anywhere.